# How to get document in subcollection shortly after it has been added?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I wonder if there's a method that will provide me with the object I will have just added to this subcollection without the need to rewrite the whole request.

```
const businessRef = firebase.firestore().collection('movies').doc(id)

businessRef
  .collection('counts')
  .doc(month)
  .set(counts)
  .then(() => console.log('added'))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error))
```

Comment: `counts` is the object you just wrote.  What else do you need, aside from that?

Comment: this object will be in the database and could be accessed and modified by other users. Therefore, it could possibly not be the same object as the one that I wrote and added.

Comment: Then just read the document back out if you think it could have changed.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to check if one document has changes on your workflow, I suggest you take a look at this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) where you can find multiple examples for this situation using the method  onSnapshot()

This is an example in Node JS:

```
let observer = db.collection('cities').where('state', '==', 'CA')
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
      if (change.type === 'added') {
        console.log('New city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === 'modified') {
        console.log('Modified city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === 'removed') {
        console.log('Removed city: ', change.doc.data());
      }
    });
  });
```